# how to work with NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse in NEXT.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on the **next.js 14** project and doing a payment gateway integration into that project. In the payment gateways, they have mentioned getting the payment success status by notifying the URL. This is how they have mentioned it in their documentation. But they have only provided PHP code.

Here is the code and documentation that they have provided.

**3. Verifying the Authorization Notification**

**It is critical to verify the Authorization Notification before taking any actions on the authorization response. You can do the verification using the md5sig checksum parameter that is generated & sent by PayHere along with the status params according to following logic.**

```
md5sig = strtoupper(
    md5 (
        merchant_id + 
        order_id + 
        payhere_amount + 
        payhere_currency + 
        status_code + 
        strtoupper(md5(merchant_secret)) 
    ) 
)
```

Once you receive the authorization status parameters from PayHere, you can locally generate this checksum using the merchant_id, order_id, payhere_amount, payhere_currency & status_code sent by the authorization notification and the merchant_secret you have locally. Your locally generated checksum should be equal to the md5sig sent by PayHere if the authorization notification is valid.

Code Sample (PHP)

You can host this script at your notify_url.

```
<?php

$merchant_id           = $_POST['merchant_id'];
$order_id              = $_POST['order_id'];
$payhere_amount        = $_POST['payhere_amount'];
$payhere_currency      = $_POST['payhere_currency'];
$status_code           = $_POST['status_code'];
$md5sig                = $_POST['md5sig'];
$status_message        = $_POST['status_message'];
$authorization_token   = $_POST['authorization_token'];

$merchant_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // Replace with your Merchant Secret

$local_md5sig = strtoupper(
    md5(
        $merchant_id . 
        $order_id . 
        $payhere_amount . 
        $payhere_currency . 
        $status_code . 
        strtoupper(md5($merchant_secret)) 
    ) 
);
       
if (($local_md5sig === $md5sig) AND ($status_code == 2) ){
    //TODO: Store the encrypted token ($authorization_token) securely in your database against your customer
}


?>
```

***Attention:***

```
Please make sure to consider the payment as successful only after the verfification, as it ensures that the authorization notification received to your notify_url was genuinely initiated by PayHere, not by any other party.
If you do not implement this verification properly, there's a security risk of a third party sending a manipulated authorization notification to your notify_url, falsly notifing that the authorization is successful.
```

(This is the link for this source page: h[ttps://support.payhere.lk/api-&-mobile-sdk/authorize-api](https://support.payhere.lk/api-&-mobile-sdk/authorize-api))

So I converted the above PHP code to typescript and I have added that code to the next.js 14 project.

this is my type of script code.

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import crypto from "crypto";
import prisma from "@/libs/prismadb";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  console.log("...............URL TRUE..........");

  if (req.method === "POST") {
    console.log("...............URL TRUE2..........");
    try {
      const {
        merchant_id,
        order_id,
        payhere_amount,
        payhere_currency,
        status_code,
        md5sig,
      } = req.body;

      const merchant_secret =
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Replace with your Merchant Secret

      const local_md5sig = crypto
        .createHash("md5")
        .update(
          merchant_id +
            order_id +
            payhere_amount +
            payhere_currency +
            status_code +
            crypto.createHash("md5").update(merchant_secret).digest("hex")
        )
        .digest("hex")
        .toUpperCase();
      console.log("...............URL TRUE3..........");
      if (local_md5sig === md5sig && status_code === "2") {
        // TODO: Update your database as payment success
        console.log("...............URL TRUE4..........");
        prisma.order.update({
          where: { id: order_id },
          data: {
            status: "complete",
          },
        });
        console.log("...............URL TRUE5..........");
        res.status(200).json({ success: true });
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({
          success: false,
          error: "Invalid payment status or signature",
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error verifying payment:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Internal server error" });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", ["POST"]);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
}
```

I place this file in a separate location in my next.js project.

**This is it** [file: payhere-webhook]

[image]

This is the code where my notify URL has called

```
import { getCurrentUser } from "@/actions/getCurrentUser";
import getOrderByIntent from "@/actions/getOrderByIntent";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";


//import getOrderByIntent from "@/actions/getOrderByIntent";

const md5 = require("crypto-js/md5");

interface IPrams {
  paymentIntent: string;
}

export async function GET(
  request: NextRequest,
  { params }: { params: { id: string } }
) {
  // console.log("--------------request", params.id);
  //console.log("--------------request query", request.query);
  console.log("--------------request url", request.url.split("?")[1].split("=")[1]);
  //console.log("--------------request STATE", request.state);

  //  const params = useParams<{ paymentIntent: string }>();
  //const order = await getOrderByIntent();
  const user = await getCurrentUser();

  //const { paymentIntent } = useCart();
  const order = await getOrderByIntent(request.url.split("?")[1].split("=")[1]);
  console.log("--------------ORDER",order);
  const data = {
    merchantId: process.env.MERCHANT_ID,
    return_url: "http://localhost:3000/",
    cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/",
    notify_url: "http://localhost:3000/api/payhere-webhook",
    merchantSecret: process.env.MERCHANT_SECRET,
    first_name: user?.firstname,
    last_name: user?.lastname,
    email: user?.email,
    phone: user?.phone,
    address: user?.address,
    city: user?.city,
    country: user?.country,
    orderId: order?.id,
    items: "Mug",
    currency: "LKR",
    amount: order?.amount,
    /*
     **
     * Addtional parameters
     **
     */
    // delivery_address - Delivery Address Line1 + Line2
    // delivery_city - Delivery City
    // delivery_country - Delivery Country
    // item_name_1 - Name of Item 1
    // item_number_1 - Model number of Item 1
    // amount_1 - Unit amount of Item 1
    // quantity_1 - Quantity of Item 1
    // item_name_2 - Name of Item 2
    // item_number_2 - Model number of Item 2
    // amount_2 - Unit amount of Item 2
    // quantity_2 - Quantity of Item 2
    // (You can list rest of the items also like this)
    // platform - Referring Platform
    // custom_1 - Custom param 1 set by merchant
    // custom_2 - Custom param 2 set by merchant
  };

  const hash = generateHash(data);

  const responseData = {
    ...data,
    hash: hash,
  };

  function generateHash(data: any) {
    const { merchantId, orderId, amount, currency, merchantSecret } = data;
    const hashedSecret = md5(merchantSecret).toString().toUpperCase();
    const amountFormated = parseFloat(amount)
      .toLocaleString("en-us", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 })
      .replaceAll(",", "");
    const hash = md5(
      merchantId + orderId + amountFormated + currency + hashedSecret
    )
      .toString()
      .toUpperCase();
    return hash;
  }
  return NextResponse.json(responseData);
}
```

(This is the link from which I got this code - which is in the pay-here documentation https://support.payhere.lk/api-&-mobile-sdk/checkout-api)

**My question is still this payment success is not store in my database can anyone resolve my code ????**
I have added this project to git repository : https://github.com/gmnchamikara/payhere-nextjs

**Thank You!**

Comment: Is notify_url  working?

Comment: yes sir, its working I can access through browser

Comment: in typescript code **crypto .createHash("md5").update** using two time which make no sense

Comment: after  **crypto.createHash("md5").update** it could not return **md5sig**

Comment: I just put return  return_url but after submitting the payment response should be passed to that webhook

Comment: looking for your comments and I add a sample project to git also https://github.com/gmnchamikara/payhere-nextjs